# "win by getting a head"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

[image]

I suppose that the picture above is some kind of a joke. But I am not able to catch the point. I would understand if there was something like "where the winning means that the head will stay on your neck". Or is "get a head" an idiom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To get ahead** means to make progress, **to get ahead of** someone means to outrun or outpace them, to leave them behind.

Of course, with a guillotine, one person (the one operating the device) **gets a head** and another loses a head.

Maybe in this game the goal is to decapitate your opponents?

There's another bit of wordplay with "revolutionary".

Comment: He'll never be the *head* of a major corporation..

Comment: But politics is a career that remains open to him.

Comment: Just do not lose your head over it, though.